# Is Stack Overflow's content protected?

Tags: support, copyright, content-reuse

I mean, can I copy part of the content and put it in a website?

Can questions be distributed or published?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check the [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) badge at the bottom of every page.

Answer (score 12):

All content on StackOverflow is covered under a Creative Commons Attribution Share-Alike license.  This means that you can re-post it wherever you want as long as you attribute it to its original author and also make it available under the same license.

Answer (score 7):

Content on SO is protected by the creative commons license.  You can see the icon on the bottom right of the page.  Here is a link to the license information

https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/

Answer (score 6):

The license is linked at the bottom of the page:

https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/

I'm guessing there is an assumption that all contributors agree to license their copyrights according to that license.

But I'm not sure where users specifically agree to it, and I don't recall clicking a license agreement.