# Use Stack Overflow data

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Stack Overflow's content protected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60455/is-stack-overflows-content-protected)

Can I use the material on Stack Overflow in my own website?

Example scenario - compile a list of fiddles on Stack Overflow and list them on my site?

I've been meaning to do this for quite some time. It'd be quite useful.

Comment: @UnicornifiedBobby - Ah, I apologize. Didn't see that one. I'll take down the question

Comment: @jib - [there is no real need to take this question down.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: @Lix: It would be nice to close it, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the posts/code that is on the site is under the [Creative Commons licence.](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).  You can

- Share
- Copy
- Distribute and transmit the work
- Adapt the work
- Make commercial use of the work

as long as you [give attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) to the original authors.

> You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor (but not in any way that suggests that they endorse you or your use of the work).

In addition,

> If you alter, transform, or build upon this work, you may distribute the resulting work only under the same or similar license to this one.

Comment: Your forgot the "Share-Alike" part...or did you mean that with "Share"?